# Changing the View Technology in this Spring Boot Sample App

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

The Spring Boot OAuth2 [`authserver` sample app at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2/authserver) uses FreeMarker templates for its views, which include [`login`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/login.ftl), and [`authorize`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/authorize.ftl).  The main application class for the app is at [this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/java/demo/AuthserverApplication.java).

**What specific changes need to be made to the code in the `authserver` app in order for the `login` and `authorize` views to be served in AngularJS INSTEAD OF FreeMarker?**

Would the rigidly-defined server-side processing in this particular app require that two separate Angular single page applications be created, one for each view?  Or could one AngularJS app handle both the `login` and `authorize` views, plus other views that might be added later?  How would this get set up?

Comment: AngularJS and Freemarker are orthogonal. Freemarker generates HTML pages. AngularJS operates on HTML pages after they're already served.

Comment: @chrylis Should we then interpret your comment to mean that each FreeMarker view would correlate with its own single page application (SPA) in AngularJS?  Alternatively, is there a way to set things up so that there is only one AngularJS app instead of many SPAs?

Comment: That's one approach, unless you're loading fragments of HTML via AJAX. Generally, with an Angular application, you'd generate a single HTML page with the startup parameters with Freemarker or another template technology, and everything else happens on the Angular side.

Comment: You answered the question. Spring Boot looks for views in any folder named `resources`, `templates`, or `static`. Also, `viewControllers` in the main application class map view files to api endpoints. Therefore, following your suggestion, I simply 1.) renamed the `templates` folder to become `static` folder, 2.) renamed `login.ftl` to become `index.html`, and 3.) changed `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");` to become `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("index");` in `AuthserverApplication.java`. The login view works same, but now able to add AngularJS code

Comment: @chrylis If you want to write your suggestion as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.

Comment: The issue of how to have one AngularJS app instead of 2+ can become a separate question later.  At least for now I know how to change from FreeMarker to AngularJS based on your comment.

Comment: The question itself is still a bit unclear, and I'm not sure I can translate this thread into an answer that will be useful for future readers. If you can clarify (maybe roll your comments up into), I'd be happy to try.